# Dynamic input fields in WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery

I am trying to create dynamic input fields in a plugin I am working on. I want to add functionality to "Add/Remove and Save" options in my plugin. Something like the below attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For add and remove button functionality you have to use the jquery. Please see the code here => http://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/re8e2yov/

For save button you can use the form or ajax to save the data in option table.